# How is ASP.NET User filled in after Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, custom-membershipprovider

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application and I want to handle authentication. I have a default page that ASP.NET gave me that contains a `<asp:Login>` Control. I have created a `MembershipProvider` and filled in the `ValidateUser()` method successfully.

Now, the authentication works, but ASP.NET somehow filled in the `User.Identity` for me without me ever getting a chance to set it with the information I would like. I am not sure how this `User` is getting populated or where any of the authentication outside of my `ValidateUser()` method is happening. Where is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set by a ASP.NET HttpModule, called [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs)

HttpModules are like java filters, and they are executed before and after a request reaches the HttpHandler.  Simple flow :

`Request -> HttpModules -> HttpHandler -> HttpModules -> Client`

It sets the user based on Cookie, usually named .aspxauth

Comment: Thanks! How can I get in there and override this process then? I would like to be using my `User` information instead of what the default is doing.

Comment: Add your custom handler to `FormsAuthenticate_OnAuthenticate` event in Global.asax, and in that handler, set your custom Identity. This automatically disables FormsAuthenticationModule (Try to read the code I linked in my answer)